# What could cause a FileNotFoundException when loading an Asp.Net Core project loads its dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I just created an Asp.Net Core project in .Net 6, which reference a class library project(well, several actually), in .Net 6.

When I launch the app, I get an error:

```
FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Insert.Name.Of.My.Class.Library.Here, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The file cannot be found'
```

And then the application stops. As of now, all the projects are quite empty, just did the naming and everything, created some base classes for my entities, Dto, added some automapper profile and MediatR request/handler.

But the dll is present in my debug folder(and only once).

- I tried to remove everything( clean debug folder, also git clean -fdx) and rebuild
- reboot, remove .Vs folder of my solution
- tried to use copy local to true or false
- tried to not use copy local and have ALL the DLL placed in the same debug folder(my current solution)
- Removed and added again the referenced project
- Referenced directly the loaded project(initially it was a dependency of another project.
- triple checked that every one of my 4 project involved were having only reference to other things as project(no direct DLL referencing)

I'm a bit lost, I just took some proof of concept that I did outside our big solution, and once integrated in our big solution, I get those error while it looks exactly the same as my proof of concept.

Any lead on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Maybe the referenced DLL in the project is set on another location and not the one from your debug folder and it is in use by another project that is keeping the DLL locked... just a wild guess...

Comment: @DA But when you reference a project, you don't specify a path, right? It just takes the output path of the given project. It's one of the advantage of referencing a project and not a DLL ?

Comment: Sure, u are right. I was talking about a compiled DLL but than I saw that u mentioned "(no direct DLL referencing)"....

Comment: Did you check the version numbers of the DLL and project reference to see if they match? And the same for every DLL your dependent DLL depends on? Did you check to ensure you don't have version conflicts for multiple references to a dependency in your dependency tree? Especially check `NewtonSoft.Json` versions.

Comment: @NightOwl888 yes they do. I found the reason it was not working(see my "partial" answer) but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason, I'm not sure why though, if somebody could explain, it would be better.

Apparently, one of my colleague did put a `Directory.Build.targets` on the root of our solution. The goal was to uniformize the "CopyLocal"  to false, since we are trying to build all our DLL in the same folder to avoid I/O and duplication during the compilation.

The content was:

```
<Project>   
    <Target Name="SetAllProjectReferenceAsPublic"
        AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration" 
        BeforeTargets="ResolveProjectReferences">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration Update="@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)" >
                <Private>false</Private>
            </ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration>
            <ProjectReference Update="@(ProjectReference)" >
                <Private>false</Private>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I'm not sure why, but apparently my web projects doesn't seems to like it. I just added another file in my web directory with this and now it works:

```
<Project>
    <Target Name="SetAllProjectReferenceAsPublic"
        AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration" 
        BeforeTargets="ResolveProjectReferences">
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I understand the purpose and cascading of this Directory.Build.targets file, but I don't understand why my project, which were already having the "CopyLocal" set to false, and were already being build all in the same folder, cannot execute with this information. If somebody could explain, I would gladly  award him the points